# Simple Swift WebView not working (Xcode 6 Beta 3)

Tags: uiwebview, swift, xcode6

I was writing a simple WebView in Swift, but everytime I try to launch it in the iOS Simulator I get these errors. What is going wrong?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView

var urlpath = "http://www.google.de"

func loadAddressURL(){
    let requesturl = NSURL(string: urlpath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requesturl)
    webview.loadRequest(request)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    loadAddressURL()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
self    uiwebview.ViewController    0x7987fc70  0x7987fc70
request NSURLRequest *  0x78ebfc40  0x78ebfc40
requesturl  NSURL * ""  0x78ec0040
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply haven't connected your UIWebView to the `webview` class property

Open the assistant editor, show your xib or storyboard at left, your view controller source file at right, click on the circle at the left of the `webview` property and drag into the `UIWebView` control. Once the connection is established, run the app and it should work now

[image: Connect iboutlet]

Comment: I made the same but *@#&* UIWebView doesnt even appear, I see only white screen nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get a white page because you test on the simulator. If you test on a real device you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "!" after 'UIWebView' and unwrap "requesturl" to get your String value otherwise it's been an optional and you get error.

```
 import UIKit

 class WebViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet var webview: UIWebView!

var urlpath: String = "http://www.google.de"

func loadAddressURL(){
    let requesturl = NSURL(string: urlpath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requesturl!)
    webview.loadRequest(request)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    loadAddressURL()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```